# Unable to remove element from boost multi_index_container++

Tags: c++, boost, multi-index, boost-multi-index

Building on CentOS 7, g++ 4.8.5-28. Language standard: C++03

Working sample: https://godbolt.org/z/ijSFrK

In the method RemoveMapping, the call to `mapDb.erase(clientIter);` is failing (see sample code in link for the actual code and the compile error). I am wondering if it is because of the multiple ordered indexes which are both using composite keys and key extractor methods?

Comment: I may be reading it wrong but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558399/deleting-from-a-boost-multiindex seems to say that erase is a member of an index and not a container.  Is it a duplicate?  Something else to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579000/erase-element-per-key-from-multi-index-container-with-composite-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than

```
mapDb.erase(clientIter);
```

you have to write

```
clientView.erase(clientIter);
```

Remember that each index (view) has its own iterator type, and you can't freely interchange them. As a convenience, the container itself (`mapDb` here) behaves like its first (#0) index, so `mapDb.erase` can only accept an iterator for `serverView`.

Comment: Yes, that rather subtle detail is what had escaped me.